# Cypress API Requests: Assertions for Size and Response Time

Tags: cypress

I am using

```
cy.request()
```

for sending GET and POST requests and I wish to add following checks on the response:

1. Response time should be less than Y seconds
2. Response size should be less than X KB

for the GET request, I can use the timeout functionality to ensure that the response time is less than Y seconds

```
cy.request('www.abc.com/home',{timeout:1000}).then((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(201)
    })
```

**ISSUE 1**

I cannot use the timeout functionality with POST request; the request works fine without adding {timeout:1000}, but shows this error on adding it.

[image]

I need help with this!

**ISSUE 2**

I also need to check the response size, and I am unaware of any methods that I can use for the said purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solutions to this issue a while ago but forgot to mention them here.

**For response time:**

You can use:

```
cy.request('<method-here>','<url-here>','<body-here>').then((response)=>{
   // this assertion expects response time to be less than 1 second i.e 1000 milliseconds
   expect(response.duration).to.not.be.greaterThan(1000)   
})
```

**For response size:**

You can use:

```
cy.request('<method-here>','<url-here>','<body-here>').then((response)=>{
    // this assertion expects response size to be less than 2 kB i.e 2048 bytes
    expect(parseInt(response.headers[`content-length`])).to.be.lessThan(2048)   
})
```